# Error when add new detail row in Payments and Applications (AR302000) screen because of customization (in Acumatia ERP System)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, customization, acumatica

I have already create some customization in screen Payment and Application of Acumatica ERP. I have created new Extension of ARPaymentEntryExtension.cs

The following is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.GL;

namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
     public class ARPaymentEntryExtension: PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
     {
         #region Override Button Menu
         public override void Initialize()
         {
            Base.report.AddMenuAction(ReceiptVoucher);
         }
         #endregion

         #region Button Receipt Vocher 
         public PXAction<ARPayment> ReceiptVoucher;
         [PXButton]
         [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Receipt Voucher")]
         public IEnumerable receiptVoucher(PXAdapter adapter)
         {
             var result = adapter.Get<ARPayment>();
             foreach (ARPayment doc in result)
             {
                 object FinPeriodID;
                 if (Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].GetStatus(doc) == PXEntryStatus.Notchanged)
                 {
                     Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].SetStatus(doc, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
                 }
                 Base.Save.Press();

                 var docPeriod = (FinPeriodID = Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].GetValueExt<ARRegister.finPeriodID>(doc)) is PXFieldState ? (string)((PXFieldState)FinPeriodID).Value : (string)FinPeriodID;
                 Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                 parameters["ReferenceNbr"] = doc.RefNbr;
                 throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "AR909095", "Report");
            }
            return result;
        }
        #endregion
    }
 }
```

I used extensoin above to preview report from current screen and it works.
When user need to create new document and then add some detail document and then click on save button, it will work.

But, when user need to add another detail document and then click on save button, system will show the error message.

Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Actually the error message appear after Acumatica was upgraded into version 2017 R2 - Build 17.207.0029.
In previous version (Version 5.3 - Build 5.30.4209) it work fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: What is the goal of the code in the button? just show the report? if so you should remove the other code to mark cache updated and save.

Comment: Yes, just to show the report. Sorry, in which part that you mean ?

Comment: The code you posted is just opening a report, but also marking a cache as updated for some reason. Why not just display the report? (unless depending on unsaved changes to be displayed in the report). Why mark a cache as updated?

Comment: I already remove if condition => if (Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].GetStatus(doc) == PXEntryStatus.Notchanged)
                 {
                     Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].SetStatus(doc, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
                 } and it works. Thanks @Brendan for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by remove the following If Condition of the code:

```
if (Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].GetStatus(doc) == PXEntryStatus.Notchanged)
             {
                 Base.Caches[typeof(ARPayment)].SetStatus(doc, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
             }
```

After remove code above, the customization is work and no error.